# flot toggle series with threshold and curved lines plugin

Tags: flot

```js
var datasets = [{"label":"IT","curvedLines":{"apply":true},"threshold":[{"below":100,"color":"rgb(204, 0, 0)"},{"below":98,"color":"rgb(237, 194, 64)"}],"color":"rgb(237, 194, 64)","idx":0,"data":[{"0":1433156400000,"1":98.03},{"0":1435748400000,"1":98.04},{"0":1438426800000,"1":96.1},{"0":1441105200000,"1":97.87},{"0":1443697200000,"1":97.88},{"0":1446379200000,"1":98.07},{"0":1448971200000,"1":99.38},{"0":1451649600000,"1":99.1}]},{"label":"Network","curvedLines":{"apply":true},"threshold":[{"below":100,"color":"rgb(204, 0, 0)"},{"below":98,"color":"rgb(175, 216, 248)"}],"color":"rgb(175, 216, 248)","idx":1,"data":[{"0":1433156400000,"1":95.07},{"0":1435748400000,"1":97.8},{"0":1438426800000,"1":96.72},{"0":1441105200000,"1":97.62},{"0":1443697200000,"1":97.68},{"0":1446379200000,"1":98.49},{"0":1448971200000,"1":98.59},{"0":1451649600000,"1":98.7}]},{"label":"Success Rate","curvedLines":{"apply":true},"threshold":[{"below":100,"color":"rgb(204, 0, 0)"},{"below":98,"color":"rgb(148, 64, 237)"}],"color":"rgb(148, 64, 237)","idx":2,"data":[{"0":1433156400000,"1":95.18},{"0":1435748400000,"1":96.95},{"0":1438426800000,"1":95.96},{"0":1441105200000,"1":96.99},{"0":1443697200000,"1":96.93},{"0":1446379200000,"1":97.68},{"0":1448971200000,"1":98.58},{"0":1451649600000,"1":98.29}]}];

var options = {"series":{"lines":{"show":true},"curvedLines":{"active":true}},"xaxis":{"mode":"time","tickSize":[1,"month"],"timeformat":"%b %y"},"grid":{"clickable":true,"hoverable":true},"legend":{"noColumns":3,"show":true}};

var somePlotSuccess = null;

togglePlotSuccess = function(seriesIdx) {
 var someData = somePlotSuccess.getData();
 //console.log(seriesIdx);
 //console.log(someData[seriesIdx].lines.show);
 someData[seriesIdx].lines.show = !someData[seriesIdx].lines.show;
 //console.log(someData[seriesIdx].lines.show);
 
 somePlotSuccess.setData(someData);
 somePlotSuccess.setupGrid();
 somePlotSuccess.draw();
}

options.legend.labelFormatter = function(label, series) {
   return '<a href="#" onClick="togglePlotSuccess(' + series.idx
     + '); return false;">' + label + '</a>';
  };
  somePlotSuccess = $.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Codicode/flotanimator/master/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.threshold.min.js"></script>

<div id = "choices_CAGraph">

</div>
<div id="CAGraph" style="width:650px;height:400px">
```

If you click on the legend you will see it only show/hides the 1st series only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because of how the threshold plug-in works. You *may* only be adding 3 data series to your plot at the start, but threshold is then breaking apart those 3 data series into many more (in your example, `getData()` actually returns 9 data series the first time it's called) so that it can display the different colored lines, etc, for a particular (original) series. The original series idx "1" will no longer be the new series idx "1" (in fact I think both the new "1" and "2" belong to the original series "0" since that series has been split into 3 separate segments).

In fact, it gets worse: since you are calling `getData()`, modifying it, and then calling `setData()` with the modified data array, the number of data series increases **every single time** the `onClick` handler is called.

So, the solution is simple: don't bother saving the returned object from `$.plot()` and don't bother calling `getData()/setData()` on it, but just call `$.plot()` again from scratch in your `onClick` handler.

There is an extra property you *must* add to *each* series in the original `datasets` array:

```
"lines": {
  "show": true
},
```

otherwise you won't be able to turn it off/on in your `onClick` handler.

Then your handler becomes:

```
togglePlotSuccess = function(seriesIdx) {
  datasets[seriesIdx].lines.show = !datasets[seriesIdx].lines.show;
  $.plot($('#CAGraph'), datasets, options);
};
```